# Files added in Git Branch-A are visible in Branch-B

Tags: visual-studio-2010, git

First of all, I am new to Git. Using Git Bash, I created a feature branch 123-Feature-A using `git branch 123-Feature-A`, checked it out  and then added some files through Visual Studio 2010. Git status showed the new files, I added them using `git add .` - since I have the VS2010 Git Source Control provider installed, I can see the icon changed to indicate that the file has been added.

When I want to switch branches I run something like `git commit -a -m "added files"` in the feature branch and then switch back to the master branch.  When I am in the master branch, I see the files in VS2010, but the icon has a exclamation point and when I try to open it, VS tells me it does not exist - is there a setting in VS to hide files that I added in Brand-A, if I switch to Branch-B

Comment: I don't know VS, but I assume that you need to reload your project (F5?).

Comment: The project automatically reloads.

Comment: After adding the files in VS and before commiting, does `git status` shows the project file (`.##proj`) as modified? VS does not save it by default and it might be the reason why you are seeing new files after the branch switch.

Answer (score 4):

It's been a while, but I think when I had this same issue I installed a git extension to VS.
Try http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/354101/Source-Code-Versioning-with-Git-in-Visual-Studio Or: http://gitscc.codeplex.com/

If you install one of these, make sure to use it consistently to manage git. That will keep VS up to date.

Comment: I tried reloading and adding Git extensions -- neither worked.  I added a file and did a git status to verify that changes to the proj file were made, and they were. When I checkout a different branch, the project reloads and the file shows an exclamation mark inside the icon.

Comment: Also, when I close Visual Studio and reopen it, the file with the exclamation point is still visible.

Answer (score 1):

your workflow is totally fine from Git stand point but may be confusing for VS, assuming you have no Git support in it. Eclipse with git plugin detects this scenario just fine and if needed F5 (project refresh) resolves most of issues.

Just double check that you do have git support in your VS, i.e. that you can for example make git commits, switch branches etc. Otherwise, VS will be always confused in such scenarios, because of the way how git operates when branch is changed.